# WiX - Set Installdirectory dynamically over CustomAction [C#]

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, wix3.5, wix3.6

I'm about to create an installer, now i have to set the install-directory depending on the operation-system. My directory-tree:

```
<Property Id="TARGETDIR" Value="C:\" />
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="TARGETDIRECTORY" Name="MyApplication">
    <Directory Id="CONFIG" Name="Config">
      <Directory Id="FOLDER2" Name="Folder2" />
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

if i set the TARGETDIRECTORY in the c#-custom-action, the targetdirectory gets set correct, but the CONFIG/FOLDER2 just have the old links. How can i force them to adjust them to the new paths? because they are childs of the TARGETDIRECTORY, i guess they should do this automatically. I dont want to set it all on my own in the CustomAction, because there are even many more folders comming

here from the log file:

```
Property(S): FOLDER2 = C:\MyApplication\Config\Folder2\
Property(S): CONFIG = C:\MyApplication\Config\
Property(S): TARGETDIRECTORY = C:\Documents and Settings\MyApplication\
Property(S): TARGETDIR = C:\
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could solve the problem with SetProperty:

```
<Property Id="TARGETDIRECTORY" Value="C:\Win7\" />
<SetProperty Id="TARGETDIRECTORY" Before="CostFinalize" Value="C:\WinXP\">
  <![CDATA[VersionNT = 501]]>
</SetProperty>
```

Comment: yes, setting the property works as you are doing it before CostFinalize. I assumed you need to set it later on during the install, so custom action type 35 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368093(v=vs.85).aspx) should have worked, strange.

Answer (score 1):

This could happen if you change the install path before CostFinalize. If this is the case you need to [use a different custom action to set the path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367852%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), that allows Windows Installer to be notified about the change and update the child directories.

Comment: tried now multiple situations, but nothing worked. only the TARGETDIRECTORY got changed, but never the child-folder. now tried with SetTargetPath on Welcomedlg->Next, now getting error 2872, i guess because the Folder doesnt exists, what to do now? i have to set the path depending on the OS (Win7/WinXP). also tried with conditionally setting the properties, but no success.